# If I was given an Android App to start working on. Would that mean I also need a key to go along with it?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, groovy, google-play-console

I was given a completed app to publish to the android store...

I created an key for it...

When trying to upload it to a closed testing on the android store I get this error:

"Your Android App Bundle is signed with the wrong key. Ensure that your App Bundle is signed with the correct signing key and try again. Your App Bundle is expected to be signed with the certificate with fingerprint:

fingerprint 1

but the certificate used to sign the App Bundle you uploaded has fingerprint:

fingerprint 2"

Why and how is my App Bundle expecting a certain key?

Should I have gotten a file/key from my boss for fingerprint 1?

I am desperate for help at this point. Any you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

I tried to write this into the build.gradle file:

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file('path/to/your/keystore/your-keystore-file.jks')
        storePassword 'your_keystore_password'
        keyAlias 'your_key_alias'
        keyPassword 'your_key_password'
    }
}
```

But, it never compiles!

Comment: Original keystore file and password are the only way to authenticate the upload. They are very critical and confidential, that's why they are not (according to good practices) included in repositories. Whoever handed you down the project must provide it if they expect you to deploy updates on the store.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Pawel!

Comment: I wanted to follow up: It's not on the store yet... and they have not provided the file and password. Is there a way to clear the current fingerprint on the project? I'm looking for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

As Pawel has said, try getting the keystore file and passwords from the person who gave you the project.

However, there is another way of retrieving the key(if the app way enrolled to google play app signing) or you can still request to use a new key. Check more info on https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en